# ArrayList in Constructor

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to add values, in constructor, from an arrayList in this instance instead of static values:

**INSTANCE WITH STATIC VALUES IN CONSTRUCTOR**

```
v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ new Edge(v1,  79.83),
                             new Edge(v5,  81.15) };
```

I want to replace these values with array elements. For example:

```
v0.adjacencies = new Edge[]{ VALUES FROM ArrayList (ar2edge) };
```

I get array from this

```
for (int kk=0;kk<arvertex.size();kk++){
   Edge edges = new Edge(arvertex.get(kk),ar2.get(kk));
   ar2edge.add(edges);
}
```

Comment: All values from the `ArrayList`? Check out the `toArray()` method/

Comment: What is the problem ? What code you tried ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: make that an answer.

Comment: [`List#toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T[]%29) is what you are looking for.

Comment: How i add all values in the costructor

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Can't be too greedy, got enough for today :)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Did you really mean that? LOL :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`toArray()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) to return an array of the elements of the `ArrayList`.

```
Edge[] edges = ar2edge.toArray(new Edge[ar2edge.size()]);
```

Quoting from the linked Javadocs above:

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper
>   sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the
>   returned array is that of the specified array. If the list fits in the
>   specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is
>   allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of
>   this list.

This way, you declare your own array of the proper size, and `toArray` fills it for you.

Comment: Isn't wasteful (even completely minimal) to allocate an empty array when you can allocate the right size?

Comment: Better to pass `new Edge[ar2edge.size()]`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah, but code wise it's just as, if not more, readable.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't really find it more readable but more boilerplate code.

Comment: could you explain it more? sorry but  I am beginner

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well, we can't agree on everything :)

Comment: @user2850530 The array as an argument to `toArray` provides the type so the returned array is of the correct type.  If the passed in array is big enough, then `toArray` uses it, else it allocates its own array.

Comment: i place this Edge[] edges = ar2edge.toArray(new Edge[ar2edge.size()]); inside the loop??